# CSS Specific Div Overlay with jQuery

Tags: ajax, css, overlay, loading

Heyya,

I have a dashboard in an application which contains quite a few div's and each div's inner html is set via remote ajax calls. What I need to do is to put a loading animation (an overlay loading with spinner etc.) **to the each of those divs** and once the ajax callback is done, i shall remove those loading overlays...

I have come to this point so far, but I cant get it inside a specific div, this loading goes all over the page, regardless where I put the loading div :( Any ideas?

```
<div class="profile-sidebar" style="width: 250px;" id="divUserProfileInfo">
            <div class="loading">Loading&#8230;</div> etc etc etc </div></div>
```

The css:

```css
.loading {

  position: fixed;

  z-index: 999;

  height: 2em;

  width: 2em;

  overflow: show;

  margin: auto;

  top: 0;

  left: 0;

  bottom: 0;

  right: 0;

}

/* Transparent Overlay */

.loading:before {

  content: '';

  display: block;

  position: fixed;

  top: 0;

  left: 0;

  width: 100%;

  height: 100%;

  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

}

/* :not(:required) hides these rules from IE9 and below */

.loading:not(:required) {

  /* hide "loading..." text */

  font: 0/0 a;

  color: transparent;

  text-shadow: none;

  background-color: transparent;

  border: 0;

}

.loading:not(:required):after {

  content: '';

  display: block;

  font-size: 10px;

  width: 1em;

  height: 1em;

  margin-top: -0.5em;

  -webkit-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;

  -moz-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;

  -ms-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;

  -o-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;

  animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;

  border-radius: 0.5em;

  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;

  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.5em 0 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;

}

/* Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {

  0% {

    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);

    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);

    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);

    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);

    transform: rotate(0deg);

  }

  100% {

    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);

    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);

    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);

    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);

    transform: rotate(360deg);

  }

}

@-moz-keyframes spinner {

  0% {

    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);

    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);

    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);

    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);

    transform: rotate(0deg);

  }

  100% {

    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);

    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);

    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);

    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);

    transform: rotate(360deg);

  }

}

@-o-keyframes spinner {

  0% {

    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);

    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);

    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);

    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);

    transform: rotate(0deg);

  }

  100% {

    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);

    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);

    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);

    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);

    transform: rotate(360deg);

  }

}

@keyframes spinner {

  0% {

    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);

    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);

    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);

    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);

    transform: rotate(0deg);

  }

  100% {

    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);

    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);

    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);

    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);

    transform: rotate(360deg);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.loading` div has a fixed position to it will positioned regardless of the position of its parent `div`. To make the `.loading` div appear only inside a specific div, change the position of `.loading` to *absolute* and the parent div's to *relative*.

Comment: I can't really change the parent div's position to relative... The theme literally falls apart after doing that... Any other suggestions?

Comment: Then make the `.loading ` 's position as relative.

Comment: By the way, I was able to put the loading div after setting those values like you said but the whole css template literally went weird :)

Comment: No mate it wont make any difference if I only change the loading's position to relative...

Comment: its only this...

.profile-sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

Comment: With jQuery you can make the necessary calculations to know where to place every `.loading` elements. You give them an absolute position and then you calculate their `top` and `left ` properties with jQuery based on the bounds of their parent divs.